# How to exclude entire Customer ID data based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to exclude all data relating to Customer ID's that have at least one instance where a condition applies. For instance:

This is all my data with conditions

```
+-------------+----------------+
| Customer ID |   Condition    |  
+-------------+----------------+
|           1 | Contacted      |  
|           1 | No Answer      |  
|           1 | Left Voicemail | 
|           1 | Spoke to       |  
|           2 | No Answer      |  
|           2 | Left Voicemail |  
|           3 | Spoke to       |  
|           3 | No Answer      |  
|           4 | Contacted      |  
|           4 | Left Voicemail |  
+-------------+----------------+
```

I need to exclude data with conditions equal to 'Contacted'. Currently, I am using the below code and getting the following results:

```
SELECT a.customerID, 
       c.condition
  FROM Tablea a
  JOIN Tablec c ON
  c.customerID = a.customerID
  WHERE c.condition NOT LIKE 'Contacted'
```

```
+-------------+----------------+
| Customer ID |   Condition    |  
+-------------+----------------+ 
|           1 | No Answer      |  
|           1 | Left Voicemail | 
|           1 | Spoke to       |  
|           2 | No Answer      |  
|           2 | Left Voicemail |  
|           3 | Spoke to       |  
|           3 | No Answer      |    
|           4 | Left Voicemail |  
+-------------+----------------+
```

However, I would like to exclude all of the Customer ID rows if the Customer ID has the condition. Ideally the code would produce the following:

```
+-------------+----------------+
| Customer ID |   Condition    |  
+-------------+----------------+ 
|           2 | No Answer      |  
|           2 | Left Voicemail |  
|           3 | Spoke to       |  
|           3 | No Answer      |  
+-------------+----------------+
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the results you are looking for:

```
Select customerid, condition from
Tablec c
WHERE customerid NOT IN
(
   Select customerid from
   Tablec
   WHERE condition LIKE 'Contacted'
)
```

In your above example I am uncertain as to why you are joining to Tablea, as you aren't pulling any data from that table except for customerID, which is already in Tablec.

However if you wanted to do the join, you could do:

```
Select a.customerID, c.condition from Tablea a
JOIN Tablec c ON c.customerID = a.customerID
WHERE c.customerid NOT IN
(
   Select customerid from
   Tablec 
   WHERE condition LIKE 'Contacted'
)
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick, thanks everyone for the input! I simplified the above table, there are also other variables included in the data so the join is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using `not exists`:

```
select customerid, condition
from Tablec c
where not exists (
    select 1
    from Tablec c2 
    where c.customerid = c2.customerid and c2.condition = 'Contacted'
)
```

This only uses `Tablec` since it appears to have both `customerid` and `condition`.  You can always join it back to `TableA` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly hacky but I'm not sure what you're original dataset looks like.

```
SELECT a.customerID, 
       c.condition
FROM Tablea a

INNER JOIN Tablec c ON
  c.customerID = a.customerID

WHERE c.customerID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT a2.customerID
        FROM Tablec a2
        WHERE a2.condition = 'Contacted'
     )
```